# Is there a way to add an additional field to Grails JSON response?

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I want every JSON response to post-request to contain a field `success`. What's the best way to add this field there?

I use code like this to generate JSON responses:

```
try {
    def entity = myService.saveEntity(arg1,arg2)
    render entity as JSON //I want to add artificial field 'success = "yes"' here
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    render parseErrors(e.errors) as JSON //field 'success = "no"' here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I just struggled with this exact issue this week. I wanted to send back a domain class as JSON but at the same time add an 'errorMessage' property that would potentially contain additional information.

Turns out that when using **as JSON** in grails it sends back a converter object, but its possible to turn that converter instance into a jsonObject using **JSON.parse()** which we can easily add new values to.

```
def jsonObject = JSON.parse((entity AS JSON).toString())
jsonObject.put("success", "yes")
render jsonObject as JSON
```

I think there are a couple of different approaches but this ended up being the easiest for me since I already have custom converters for most of my domain classes and I didn't want to add any other transient properties to my domain object.

Comment: the simplest solution by far. I vote that this be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

Could you return a map containing the `success` field, and the object wrapped inside a separate variable:

```
try {
    def entity = myService.saveEntity(arg1,arg2)
    render [ success:'yes', val:entity ] as JSON
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    render [ success:'no', val:parseErrors(e.errors) ] as JSON
}
```

Not tested it mind...

Answer (score 4):

You can register your own JSON marshaller (at `BootStrap.groovy`, for example), like:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(MyEntity) { MyEntity it ->
  return [
    someField : it.someField, // you should specify fields for output, or put all '.properties'
    success   : true // as I understand you always have 'true' for real entity
  ]
}
```

where `MyEntity` is your class you want to use